# Parsing several Internet pages simultaneously

Tags: perl

There is a list of (unrelated) Internet pages I'd like to load simultaneously.
I wouldn't mind parsing the information itself page after page, but I thought to myself, that if my browser can load two and more pages simultaneously, why shouldn't Perl do that?

I'm afraid I couldn't find anything like that on the Internet, so I am asking you.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you, I will see if something interesting was posted there. Sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Parallel::ForkManager](http://p3rl.org/Parallel%3a%3aForkManager) is your friend.  Tell it how many you want to do simultaneously and loop through your list.

Comment: That seems to be the solution. I'll have a look. Thank you!